# tflearn DNN gives zero loss

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I am using `pandas` to extract my `data`. To get an idea of my `data` I replicated an example dataset...

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

which yields a dataset of `shape=(100,4)`...

```
    A   B   C   D
0  75  38  81  58
1  36  92  80  79
2  22  40  19  3
   ...    ...
```

I am using `tflearn` so I will need a target label as well. So I created a target label by extracting one of the columns from `data` and then dropped it out of the `data` variable (I also converted everything to `numpy` arrays)...

```
# Target label used for training
labels = np.array(data['A'].values, dtype=np.float32)

# Reshape target label from (100,) to (100, 1)
labels = np.reshape(labels, (-1, 1))

# Data for training minus the target label.
data = np.array(data.drop('A', axis=1).values, dtype=np.float32)
```

Then I take the `data` and the `labels` and feed it into the DNN...

```
# Deep Neural Network.    
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model.
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
```

This seems like it should work, but the output I get is as follows...

[image]

Notice that the `loss` remains at `0`, so I am definitely doing something wrong. I don't really know what form my data should be in. How can I get my training to work?

Comment: Could you provide a sample dataset that one could idly run against complete-enough code that exhibits the symptoms you're describing?

Comment: You mean "question", and I have no qualms here.  I don't do Pandas or NumPy, so you'll want to wait for someone who does to come along and answer.  Since you provide enough to replicate the issue...I don't really see a problem, but someone else with a trained eye may.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual output is in range 0 to 100 while the activation softmax in  the outermost layer outputs in range [0, 1]. You need to fix that. Also the default loss for tflearn.regression is categorical cross entropy which is used for classification problems and makes no sense in your scenario. You should try L2 loss. The reason you are getting zero error in this setting is that your network predicts 0 for all training examples and if you fit that value in formula for sigmoid cross entropy, loss indeed is zero. Here is its formula , where t[i] denotes the actual probabilities (which doesnt make sense in your problem) and o[i] is the predicted probabilities.

[image: equation]

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223256/tensorflow-cross-entropy-for-regression) is more reasoning about why default choice of loss function is not suitable for your case

Comment: This was helpful, thank you, I did some research and ended up implementing a linear regression instead with `optimizer=sgd` and `loss=mean_square`, I guess I realize now that softmax is basically like the sigmoid function and is used for classification problems instead.

Comment: Also I am not sure why this question is still downvoted, I edited my question so I don't think it is worth a downvote.